# Bootstrap 3 Popover gets hidden behind the element which overflow is hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

Please take some seconds at have a glance at the code first. I'm using BS3.

The HTML

```
<div class="my-div">
  <a href="#">A link</a>
</div>
<div class="cool-div">
 <p>bla and bla</p>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
// Make PopOver stay while one mouseover on it
var originalLeave = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave = function(obj){
  var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
    obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type)
  var container, timeout;

  originalLeave.call(this, obj);

  if(obj.currentTarget) {
    container = $(obj.currentTarget).siblings('.popover')
    timeout = self.timeout;
    container.one('mouseenter', function(){
      //We entered the actual popover – call off the dogs
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      //Let's monitor popover content instead
      container.one('mouseleave', function(){
        $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave.call(self, self);
      });
    })
  }
};

// Show User Details PoPOver 
$('.my-div').popover({
    trigger: 'hover', 
    placement: 'auto',
    html:true, 
    delay: {show: 50, hide: 400}, 
    content: function () {
            return $(this).next('.cool-div').html();
        }
});

// Make some custom styling on User Details PoPOver 
$(function () {
    $('.my-div').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            popover = $this.next('.popover');
            popover.find('.popover-content').css({padding: '5px 5px 8px 5px', 'margin-right':'-18px'});
    });
});
```

Ok, so what I did was I made the PopOver stay while one mouseover on it at the first piece of code and followed by showing it and some custom styling.

Now, everything is fine but in some smaller resolution I have a div which is *overflow:hidden* causing my Popover gets hidden behind in it. 
I increase the value of z-index of the *.popover*, didnt work..
I researched and tried with *container:'body'* or *container:'my-div'* as well as *data-container="body"* in html.

Though it solves the problem but the popover is not staying while on mouseover in it as well as the css is not getting attached as well.

How can I achieve all these three together?
Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the complete sample of your code please, including that div that has overflow:hidden on it so I can take a look at the complete problem.
I don't know where you placed the other div so its a bit hard to solve now :)

Here some propably unwanted advice :)

I usually add(or toggle) a CSS to an element I want to control instead of adding CSS attributes to it.
So instead of:

> popover.find('.popover-content').css({padding: '5px 5px 8px 5px', 'margin-right':'-18px'});

I would use:

> popover.find('.popover-content').addClass("styleme");

Regards,